# Empty line during transfer XML to CSV using xsl

Tags: java, xml, csv, xslt, xml-parsing

I have below code to transfer XML to CSV, but into output (in csv), first line is blank (empty).

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

**Java class**:

```
public class ReadXML {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        File stylesheet = new File("C:\\style.xsl");
        File xmlSource = new File("C:\\data.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
                Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

                Source source = new DOMSource(document);

                Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\x.csv"));
        transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    }
}
```

**XSL stylesheet:** (style.xsl)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
MsgId,PartnerId,OrderId
<xsl:for-each select="//orderDetails">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(MsgId,',',PartnerId,',',OrderId,'&#xA;')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML data**: (data.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <orderDetails>
        <MsgId>text1</MsgId>
        <PartnerId>text1</PartnerId>
        <OrderId>text1</OrderId>
    </orderDetails>
    <orderDetails>
        <MsgId>text11</MsgId>
        <PartnerId>text11</PartnerId>
        <OrderId>text11</OrderId>
    </orderDetails>
</orders>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert header in the element xsl:text:

```
<xsl:text>MsgId,PartnerId,OrderId
</xsl:text>
```